# Single client per VLAN in /24 network

Tags: vlan, private-vlan

I have a single /24 IP network. I want to make a VLAN (or something) and distribute a single IP and gateway per client. Each client should not be able to talk to each other.

What is the best way to do this?

**Update:**

I am using MikroTik router and a Cisco 2950 layer 2 switch.

Comment: What kind of switch/router are you using?

Comment: mikrotik router with cisco 2950 layer 2 switch

Comment: If your code is new enough, you can use private vlans for this.  Can you post the output of "show int fa 0/1 switch"?

Comment: is it possible to make vlan on router?

Comment: I don't know for sure, as I am unfamiliar with Mikrotik.  If you can create private vlans on the switch, you will not need vlans on your router.

Comment: keep in mind that some routers/switches have a maximum number of vlan's allowed on their devices.

Comment: If he is running the "router on a stick" structure it is not necessary that the router supports VLANs. The uplink could be on an access port on the primary vlan and in promiscuous mode. The private vlans are transparent to L3 devices even on  trunk ports.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

Cisco Catalyst switches have the concept of private vlans which should accomplish what you are trying to do.

> In some situations, you need to prevent Layer 2 (L2) connectivity
>   between end devices on a switch without the placement of the devices
>   in different IP subnets. This setup prevents the waste of IP
>   addresses. Private VLANs (PVLANs) allow the isolation at Layer 2 of
>   devices in the same IP subnet. You can restrict some ports on the
>   switch to reach only specific ports [snip].

This document should work for 2960 model switches as well:

[Configuring Isolated Private VLANs on Catalyst Switches](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/private-vlans-pvlans-promiscuous-isolated-community/40781-194.html)

Answer (score 3):

A better solution (and more simple than private vlans) would be using **switchport protected**.

`Switchport Protected` is a command you can apply on a per-interface basis.  The way it works, is if two interfaces are marked protected, they are unable to speak to each other.  Here is a picture:

[image: Switchport Protected]

In the picture above, both hostA and hostB are connected to the same switch, and in the same VLAN.  Additionally, both switch ports that they are connected to (fa0/1 and fa0/4 in this case) have been configured with **switchport protected**.  The Router, which is acting as their default gateway, is connected to fa0/12, and is *NOT* configured with switchport protected.  Therefore, HostA and HostB can each speak to the Router, but HostA and HostB are unable to speak to each other, since they are both configured as protected ports.

Protected ports can not speak to protected ports
Protected ports *CAN* speak to unprotected ports
Unprotected ports have always been able to speak to unprotected ports (given same VLAN, et al).

Using this, you can configure all your hosts in the same VLAN, with the same IP Network, and the Router can act as the DHCP server (if necessary) for just that single VLAN.  But with all the ports configured with `switchport protected` (except the uplink to the router, of course), none of the Hosts will see each other, but they will all be able to see the Router and speak out to the Internet.

The configuration for the setup above would be something like this:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
  switchport access vlan 10
  switchport mode access
  switchport protected
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
  switchport access vlan 10
  switchport mode access
  switchport protected
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
  switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
  switchport mode trunk
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Additionally, to prevent unknown unicast and unknown multicast frames from being sent to your protected ports you can include the `switchport block unicast` and `switchport block multicast` to the configuration above. [Reference Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3560/software/release/12-2_58_se/configuration/guide/3560scg/swtrafc.html#wp1175133)

Answer (score 2):

We have a similar setup, with a single /24 public range.

At the time, I was not aware that the 2950 switches could support PVLANs (which coincidentally is what we've also been running). Instead, to conserve IP space, I used the following configuration:

- Router on a stick - each client is assigned their own VLAN and their own **private** IP range. Eg. 10.1.2.0/28 - or whatever size makes sense.
- From that point, terminate each VLAN on the router, so it becomes responsible for inter-VLAN routing. This allows you to run ACLs to prevent unwanted communication between customer subnets. *I have no evidence for this* but I would suggest that, given the 2950 hardware is dated, depending on the model of your MikroTik router, you will be able to run more ACLs on the MikroTik.

(As an aside, we're currently using a Linux router - 8 cores + 8 GB RAM, and it handles just under 1000 individual IPTables rules without breaking a sweat - though the throughput is < 50 Mbps).

- Perform 1:1 static NAT on the MikroTik router, this allows you to use only a single public IP address per server/client. You could choose to route segments of your public space directly to a VLAN, as needed, as well.

We've found this to be a pretty flexible configuration. As long as you're not planning to scale to a much larger size, I think it works well.

I'm not saying that this would necessarily be a better solution over PVLANs, but simply offering it as an alternative that has worked for us so far.

To be honest with you, though, if I had've realised at the time I could get a PVLAN configuration working on the 2950s, then I probably would have done that instead.

### Edit - Virtual Machines

Again, I'm not entirely sure how this might compare with PVLANs, but one of the major benefits we've experienced in our setup, is that it works seamlessly on our virtual platform.

For each virtual server host, it is configured with a trunk port, and we simply define virtual networks per VLAN, which each VM can belong to, as needed. This means that we can have customers with multiple physical servers, and VMs across multiple hosts, and span their specific VLAN across all of them.

Meaning they can talk to all of their servers/VMs "locally" but still remain isolated from all other customers on our infrastructure.

I would consider this a major benefit of our configuration. I'm not sure you'd be able to bring PVLANs down to your ESX/Xen/Virtual Hosts, which would limit your options.

Answer (score 1):

On 2950 switches you can use assign VLANs on a /24 network, you would have to use inter-VLAN routing to route these VLANs from layer 2 to Layer 3 but I am not familiar with  MikroTik router. You will have to create sub-interfaces on your router to distribute the IP addresses range to each vlan using the 802.1q encapsulation.

Just remember, on Cisco switches native VLAN is set to default `Vlan 1` it is best security practice to change it to an unused vlan. Native VLANs should be configured on both ends of the trunk interface and if you have multiple switches, it is recommended to use VTP

VLAN10 192.168.10.1
VLAN20 192.168.20.1
VLAN30 192.168.30.1
VLAN40 192.168.50.1 -> native vlan

**create vlans**

```
SW1>en
SW1#conf t
SW1(config)vlan 10
SW1(config-vlan)name (vlan name)
```

**assign switchports to vlans**

```
SW1>int fa0/1
SW1>int range fa0/1 - fa0/10
SW1>switchport mode access
SW1>switchport access vlan 10
```

**set default-gateway**

```
SW1>ip default-gateway 192.168.1.1
```

On a 7500 router you can do these codes/commads to use "router on a stick"

```
Router(config)#int fa0/0
Router(config-if)#no shut
Router(config-if)#
%LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface FastEthernet0/0, changed state to up
%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/0, changed state to up
Router(config-if)#int fa0/0.10
Router(config-subif)#
%LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface FastEthernet0/0.10, changed state to up
%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/0.10, changed state to up
Router(config-subif)#encap ?
  dot1Q  IEEE 802.1Q Virtual LAN
Router(config-subif)#encap 
Router(config-subif)#encap dot1Q  ?
  <1-1005>  IEEE 802.1Q VLAN ID
Router(config-subif)#encap dot1Q 10
Router(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
Router(config-subif)#int fa0/0.20
Router(config-subif)#
%LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface FastEthernet0/0.20, changed state to up
%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/0.20, changed state to up
Router(config-subif)#encap dot1Q 20
Router(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
Router(config-subif)#int fa0/0.30
Router(config-subif)#
%LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface FastEthernet0/0.30, changed state to up
%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/0.30, changed state to up
Router(config-subif)#encap dot1Q 30
Router(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
Router(config-subif)#int fa0/0.55
Router(config-subif)#
%LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface FastEthernet0/0.55, changed state to up
%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/0.55, changed state to up
Router(config-subif)#encap dot1Q 55 ?
  native  Make this as native vlan
  <cr>
Router(config-subif)#encap dot1Q 55 native
Router(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.55.1 255.255.255.0
Router(config-subif)#int fa0/0.77
Router(config-subif)#
%LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface FastEthernet0/0.77, changed state to up
%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/0.77, changed state to up
Router(config-subif)#encap dot1Q 77
Router(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.77.1 255.255.255.0
Router(config-subif)#
Router(config-subif)#^Z
Router#
%SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
Router#
Router#wr
Building configuration...
[OK]
Router#
Router#copy run start
Destination filename [startup-config]?
Building configuration...
[OK]
Router#sh ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, I - IGRP, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route
Gateway of last resort is not set
C    192.168.10.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0.10
C    192.168.20.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0.20
C    192.168.30.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0.30
C    192.168.55.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0.55
C    192.168.77.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0.77
Router#
```